# UI freezes whenever I try to send multiple requests to write data into firebase (angular8/node.js)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an Excel file that I read with xlsx, convert data to json like objects and write in firebase with a loop(for), my write function into firebase returns a promise and with this method my UI freezes whenever I send multiple requests (1k+). I've tried to simulate the same code with async await but I get like 1 iteration per second which is very long if you have 100 000+ data.

The solution I'm looking for is to push chunks of data into firebase (I tried with 200 rows of data no problem I get everything in like 2 seconds).
I'm resolving my promise but I fear that it is the one causing memory leaks therefore UI freezes.

```
arr = [{key1: value1, key2:value2,...},...,{keyX,:valueX,...,}]

async uploadFb(arr: Array<object>) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const element = arr[i];
        console.log("index is : ", i)
        await this._Service.addAsset(element).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        })
    }
}
```

and I call my function normally:

```
this.uploadFb(arr)
```

the structure I'm hoping to get in firebase is:

[image: for each object in the array]

Comment: From what you shared it is impossible to say how this calls Firebase. Please make sure that the code you shared can be run by any of us. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)